# Linux 'top' utility wildly inaccurate (more so for multi-CPU/core hardware)?

Tags: linux, cpu, monitoring, multi-core

After using `top` for long time, albeit basically, I have grown to distrust its `% CPU` column reports. I have an 8-core (quad core Intel i7 920 with hyperthreading) hardware, and see some wild numbers when running a process that should not use more than 5% overall. `top` happily reports 50%, and I suspect it is not so.

My question is, is it a known fact that it's inaccurate when several CPUs/cores are present?

I used `mpstat` from the `sysstat` package, and its showings are much more conservative, certainly within my expectations. I did press `1` for `top` to switch it to show all the core and us/sy/io stats, but the numbers are substantially higher than with `mpstat`...

I know that my expectations could be unfounded as well, but my gut feeling tells me `top` is wrong!

The reason I need to know is because the process I am monitoring only guarantees quality of service with CPU usage "less than 80%" (however vague that sounds), and I need to know how much headroom I have left. It's a streaming server.

Comment: What CPU usage number in `top` do you talk about? Single or SMP mode?

Comment: Both single and SMP report a total that is about twice as high as numbers reported by mpstat.

Comment: Try to install htop. That is is a better version (in my opinion) of top. See what results you get there first.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can run top in interactive mode by pressing 'I' and it normalizes the %CPU time by dividing by the total number of CPUs.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that a full load on your system would be 800% (100% for each core)

Comment: Well, isn't 800% a mathematical impossibility or something :-)
That's sort of what it boils down to - wouldn't it be better for 'top' to adjust its reports so that 100% is 100% of the entire CPU array usage space?
So, currently, my 50% reported have to be divided by 8 to get a more meaningful number, right?

Comment: Although 800% seems silly, it makes it obvious that multiple cores are being used. I think it's a reasonable kludge when you don't have a distinct list of CPU utilization per core. Scaling the measurement to be within 100% wouldn't tell the user if a process was multi-core or not.